# bash : evaluate function return value with spaces in arguments

Tags: bash

I have:

```
func() {
        echo a "b c"
}

set $(func)

echo 1: $1
echo 2: $2
echo 3: $3
```

I want to get two arguments: "a" and "b c". How should func() echo to achieve that?

Tried as above.
Getting

```
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

I want

```
1: a
2: b c
3:
```

Comment: Well, the output of `func` is `a b c`, so how would you know which letters are to be grouped together?

Answer (score 2):

> How should func() echo to achieve that?

It is not possible to do that. No matter the content of `func()`, it's impossible with `set $(func)` to achieve that.

Prefer:

```
func() {
    array=(a "b c")
}
func
set -- "${array[@]}"
```

Do not use, because `eval` is evil:

```
func() {
    printf "%q " a "b c"
}
eval "set -- $(func)"
```

Comment: IMHO array is local to func() and not available after func() finishes.

Comment: I disagree. There is no `local` in the function. `array` is not local and the code works as presented completely fine. In Bash, variables have global (process) scope, unless declared with `local` or `declare` in a function.

Comment: This surprises me, but you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Bash's `mapfile` can be used to read a stream of null-delimited values output from a function into an array.

Applied to question:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

func() {
  printf '%s\0' a "b c"
}

mapfile -d '' arr < <(func)

echo 1: "${arr[0]}"
echo 2: "${arr[1]}"
echo 3: "${arr[2]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

2 mistakes:
You forgot to escape the quotes, so your output is:

```
 $ echo a "b c"
 a b c
```

What you want is:

```
 $ echo a \"b c\"
 a "b c"
```

And you have to evaluate the response:

```
eval set $(func)
```

That's all

Comment: Does not work for me. The result are still three arguments.

```func() {
        echo a "b c"
}

eval set $(func)

echo 1: $1
echo 2: $2
echo 3: $3
```

Comment: Your comment seems to suggest that you forgot the back slashes in the function. They are essential. So `func() {         echo a \"b c\" }`

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the array variant, it looks too complicated. But I was able to restructure my code, avoiding this problem.